# How to reset leaflet map markers in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I created a Shiny app that performs data intersections on a Leaflet map. First, the user can filter the data. Then, when at least three points are clicked on the map, a polygon is created and the markers inside the polygon are intersected.

However, I am having trouble resetting the data to its original state before the intersection. I have provided a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(geodaData) #dataset

sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)

#jeu de données
vehicle_pts <- vehicle_pts |> st_as_sf(vehicle_pts) #points

#object vide pour les click
clicks <- data.frame(lat = numeric(), lng = numeric(), .nonce = numeric()) 


# Définir l'interface utilisateur
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Application Shiny avec carte Leaflet et intersection de données"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = 'Police_Dept', label = "Choisir un département", choices = unique(sort(vehicle_pts$PoliceD)), selected =  3),
      actionButton(inputId = "intersection", label = "Afficher l'intersection", value = FALSE),
      actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reinitialiser les points", value = FALSE)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("carte")
    )
  )
)

# Définir le serveur
server <- function(input, session, output) {
  
  #creation des points
  point <- eventReactive(input$carte_click, {
    df <- data.frame(lng = input$carte_click$lng, lat = input$carte_click$lat)
    last_click <- isolate(as.data.frame(input$carte_click))
    clicks <<- clicks |>
      bind_rows(last_click)
    print(clicks)
  })
  
  #creation des points sur la carte
  observeEvent(point(), {
    leafletProxy("carte") |> 
      addCircleMarkers(lng = input$carte_click$lng, lat = input$carte_click$lat, 
                       color = 'red', weight = 1, radius = 4, fillOpacity =1)
    
  })
  
  #cration du polygone
  intersection_poly <- reactive({
    req(nrow(point()) >= 3)
    
    polygon_inter <- point() |> 
      st_as_sf(coords = c("lng", "lat"), crs = 4326) |> 
      summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) |> 
      st_cast("POLYGON")
    
    polygon_inter <- st_transform(polygon_inter, crs = 7801) #convertir en utm pour buffer
    polygon_inter <- st_buffer(polygon_inter, dist = 1)      #prevenir les auto-intersections
    polygon_inter <- st_transform(polygon_inter, crs = 4326)
  })
  

  #filtrer les données
  results <- reactive({
    
    df <- vehicle_pts |> filter(PoliceD %in% input$Police_Dept)
    
    if(input$intersection){
      
      df <- vehicle_pts |> filter(PoliceD %in% input$Police_Dept)
      df <- st_intersection(df, intersection_poly())
      
    }else{
      
      df <- vehicle_pts |> filter(PoliceD %in% input$Police_Dept)
    }
    
    df
    
  })
  
#carte des données
  output$carte <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(vehicle_pts) %>% 
      setView(lat = 41.7606, lng = -87.6149, zoom = 12) |> 
      addTiles() # Ajouter les tuiles de la carte
  })

#proxy
observe({
  
  leafletProxy("carte", data = results()) |> 
    clearMarkers() |> 
    addMarkers()
  
  
  #réinitialiser les données
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    
    #réinitialiser les clics
    pts_carte <- NULL
    clicks <<- pts_carte |> data.frame(lat = numeric(), lng = numeric())
    
    #efface les marqueurs!!!
    leafletProxy("carte", data = results()) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers()
    

  })
  
  
  
})


}

# Lancer l'application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried to reset the data using a button. When I click the button, the recorded clicks and markers are removed. However, if I try to use the filter again, the behavior is as if the intersection is still active.

**Edit**: I corrected the mistake pointed out by Remko Duursma and added `vehicle_pt <- vehicle_pts |> filter(PoliceD %in% input$Police_Dept)` in my observeEvent to make it work. Not sure is the best way to do it but a least this is functional. Here is my corrected version:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(geodaData)

sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)

#jeu de données
vehicle_pt <- vehicle_pts |> st_as_sf(vehicle_pts) #points

#object vide pour les click
clicks <- data.frame(lat = numeric(), lng = numeric(), .nonce = numeric()) 


# Définir l'interface utilisateur
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Application Shiny avec carte Leaflet et intersection de données"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = 'Police_Dept', label = "Choisir un département", choices = unique(sort(vehicle_pt$PoliceD)), selected =  3),
      actionButton(inputId = "intersection", label = "Afficher l'intersection", value = FALSE),
      actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reinitialiser les points", value = FALSE)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("carte")
    )
  )
)

# Définir le serveur
server <- function(input, session, output) {
  
  #creation des points
  point <- eventReactive(input$carte_click, {
    df <- data.frame(lng = input$carte_click$lng, lat = input$carte_click$lat)
    last_click <- isolate(as.data.frame(input$carte_click))
    clicks <<- clicks |>
      bind_rows(last_click)
    print(clicks)
  })
  
  #creation des points sur la carte
  observeEvent(point(), {
    leafletProxy("carte") |> 
      addCircleMarkers(lng = input$carte_click$lng, lat = input$carte_click$lat, 
                       color = 'red', weight = 1, radius = 4, fillOpacity =1)
    
  })
  
  #cration du polygone
  #intersection_poly <- reactive({
  intersection_poly <-eventReactive(input$intersection, {
    
    req(nrow(point()) >= 3)
    
    polygon_inter <- point() |> 
      st_as_sf(coords = c("lng", "lat"), crs = 4326) |> 
      summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) |> 
      st_cast("POLYGON")
    
    polygon_inter <- st_transform(polygon_inter, crs = 7801) #convertir en utm pour buffer
    polygon_inter <- st_buffer(polygon_inter, dist = 1)      #prevenir les auto-intersections
    polygon_inter <- st_transform(polygon_inter, crs = 4326)
  })
  
  
  #filtrer les données
  results <- reactive({
    
    df <- vehicle_pt |> filter(PoliceD %in% input$Police_Dept)
    
    if(input$intersection){
      
      df <- vehicle_pt |> filter(PoliceD %in% input$Police_Dept)
      df <- st_intersection(df, intersection_poly())
      
    }else if(input$reset){
      
      df <- vehicle_pt |> filter(PoliceD %in% input$Police_Dept)
      
    }else{
      
      df <- vehicle_pt |> filter(PoliceD %in% input$Police_Dept)
    }
    
    df
    
  })
  
  #carte des données
  output$carte <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(vehicle_pt) %>% 
      setView(lat = 41.7606, lng = -87.6149, zoom = 12) |> 
      addTiles() # Ajouter les tuiles de la carte
  })
  
  #proxy
  observe({
    
    leafletProxy("carte", data = results()) |> 
      clearMarkers() |> 
      addMarkers()
    
  })
  
  
  #réinitialiser les données
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    
    #réinitialiser les clics
    pts_carte <- NULL
    clicks <<- pts_carte |> data.frame(lat = numeric(), lng = numeric())
    
    vehicle_pt <- vehicle_pts |> filter(PoliceD %in% input$Police_Dept)
    
    #efface les marqueurs!!!
    leafletProxy("carte", data = vehicle_pt) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers() 
    
    
  })
  
  
  
  
  
}

# Lancer l'application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It seems you have defined your `observeEvent` for the reset button *inside* an `observe` block, that will give problems for sure.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this mistake to me. I have corrected the mistake and added `vehicle_pt <- vehicle_pts |> filter(PoliceD %in% input$Police_Dept)` to my observeEvent to make it work.